# Firefox displays unsupported audio warning

Tags: html, html5-audio

I created a test html page for playing an audio file when I click a button:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Audio-test</title>
  </head> 
  <body>  
    <button id="button1">play</button>
    <script>
      var audio1 = new Audio("error.mp3");
      document.querySelector("#button1").addEventListener('click',
         (evt) => audio1.play());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Firefox 84 (on Ubuntu) gives me a warning

> Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: audio/mpeg

however the **playback works** when I click the button.

Chrome does not complain at all.

I'm afraid that this implementation is fragile (because of the warning) and would like to know what this warning is about and if I'm missing some important trick when playing audio files from JavaScript.

Comment: look it, pls - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/999164

Comment: This is for Firefox 29 under windows and apparently some problems with flash or other plugins. The config options in the provided solutions do not even exist in Firefox 84 on Ubuntu :(